# How to install Processing-Java in Windows 10?

Tags: java, windows, image-processing, processing

I know that you can install processing-java using the tools menu in processing 3 app but it only works in macOS. In windows there is no option to install processing-java from the tools menu.

[image: Processing 3]

Furthermore, I tried installing using the 'processing-java.exe' in the installed folder ;

[image: Processing 3 folder]

but it will just open a cmd window and it will get closed as soon as it pops up.
Additionally, I tried typing the command `processing-java` in cmd prompt and it says it isn't a command. Finally, can some tell me how to install processing-java.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: No mate, I didn't try it afterwards. Check the below answers and see. If any of the below answers work let me know I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install anything, and `processing-java.exe` doesn't actually display anything. You need to run it via the command line, and you need to give it arguments to work.

Open a command line to the directory that contains `processing-java.exe` and then type `processing-java.exe` and hit enter. You should see an output of the arguments you can feed the tool.

Also note that 99% of Processing users never have to touch this tool, so make sure you actually need it before you try using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get 'command not found' error. By the way, I think I need the processing-java because I'm using it to post images to Twitter using Twitter API and Nodejs (I'm following a tutorial on Twitter bots).

Comment: @LordDraagon The `processing-java` tool is designed to convert Processing code into Java code. If you just want to use Processing as a Java library, there are easier ways to do that. See [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) for more info. Also it doesn't make a ton of sense to use Processing from node.js.

Comment: I was following  this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUoIPmZ4KwA&t=43s) but still I just wanted to activate the processing-java.exe and test it anyway

Comment: @LordDraagon I have figured out way to use processing-java in window here is link if you still looking for https://github.com/MonikaPatelIT/processing-java-in-windows

Comment: @monikapatelIT Thank you. I'll check it

Comment: Late to the party, but adding the install path of the .exe to your environment variable Path will make processing-java available to cmd from any folder.

Answer (score 0):

Without installing `processing-java` from the tool menu in the Processing app, you can still execute it in the console from anywhere using its full path, e.g. `C:\Users\yourname\Documents\processing-3.4\processing-java.exe`.
A command to run a processing sketch can be `C:\Users\yourname\Documents\processing-3.4\processing-java.exe --sketch="C:\Users\yourname\Documents\sketchFolder" --run`.